Can someone identify the next font/document settings?
I'm currently writing a paper and searching for the appropriate document settings(font, line spacing, margins etc.). I saw the next paper, and this is exactly what I've been searching for. 
This is a link to the paper.

as you have the pdf, your pdf reader font menu or pdffonts commandline tool will list teh fonts used

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture

It's just the default latex computer modern font plus amsfonts.
